# How can i show data from pivot Table in Datatables?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

i have this.

```
  columns: [
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    //array en name <---
                    return '<td><input value="'+data.id+'" class="all_del" type="checkbox" name="borrar_c[]"></input></td>';
                },
            },
            {data: 'nombre'},
            {data: 'direccion'},
            {data: 'familias.nombre'},
            {data: 'updated_at'},
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formulario" type="button" class="btn btn-warning editarmodal">Editar</a></td>';
                },
            },
            {
                data: null,
                "targets": 1,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<td><a type="button" class="btn btn-danger borrar">Borrar</a></td>';
                },

            },

        ]
```

In Datatables.
And i want to show the data from another table with Relationship Many to Many in Laravel.
and i do this for show data for Datatables.

```
   $locales = Local::with('familias','etiquetas')->where(function ($q) use ($request){

        if($request->idfamilia){
             $q->where('idfamilias',$request->idfamilia);
        }
    })->get();

    return response()->json($locales);
```

I use *familias.nombre* because it's a Foreign key with the table Familias.
and i cant use *etiquetas.nombre* because have a pivot table, how can i do it?
I want to show the field 'name' from 'etiquetas' with pivot table in datatables.

Comment: A side note: You should not return `<td></td>` in `render` callbacks, only the content within the cells.

Comment: Please do show your `Familia`, `Etiqueta` and `Local` models plus the corresponding database migrations.